# Unable to set off the guru mode in emacs prelude

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs prelude and am unable to turn off the `guru-mode`. It says in the documentation that this can be achieved by setting `(guru-mode -1)`. I have put this setting in the `my-init.el`, however it still doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: none of the proposed answers works for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this:

```
(add-hook 'prelude-prog-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (guru-mode -1)) t)
```

Answer (score 8):

Using 'prelude-prog-mode-hook is an option, but I would recommend to use the dedicated Prelude variable as described on the Prelude Home page http://batsov.com/prelude/

Simply add the following in your configuration (in .emacs.d/personal/<yourconfig>.el)

```
(setq prelude-guru nil)
```

Comment: That's the better solution indeed.